# pymysql error message (INSERT INTO function)

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I encountered error message (INVALID SYNTAX) and have no idea why it happens.
Please help to figure it out.

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxxxxxxx', db='ecommerce', charset='utf8')
ecommerce = db.cursor()

for index in range(10):
    product_code = 215673140 + index +1
    sql=INSERT INTO product VALUES(str(product_code),'sample data1','sample date2','sample data3');  ----> here's error point. 
    ecommerce.execute(sql)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: You just told us your MySQL credential

Comment: ```sql='INSERT...'``` the statement should be enclosed between 2 quotes

Comment: Also, ```;``` is invalid in python

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to enclose `INSERT INTO ...` inside `" "`. Also, don't use `;` after the statement.

I suggest you should use `%s`. That way, you can insert any value inside that column

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxxxxxxx', db='ecommerce', charset='utf8')
ecommerce = db.cursor()

for index in range(10):
    product_code = 215673140 + index +1
    sql = "INSERT INTO product VALUES (%s, %s,%s,%s,%s)"
    val = (str(product_code),'sample data1','sample date2','sample data3')
    ecommerce.execute(sql, val)
db.commit()
db.close()
```